# How to use either react router useParams() or window.localStorage()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

In my scenario , the component should take a value either from the URL or from `localStorage` but when I attempt to get value from useParams() it throws this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: useParams is not defined
```

My code is:

```
const { userId } = useParams() || props;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you didn't import `useParams`, in which case do so at the top of your file :

```js
import {useParams} from "react-router-dom"
```

Then do :

```js
let {userId} = useParmas();
if(!userId) userId = props.userId;
```

Because `useParams` return an object, an empty object like so `{}` if there isn't any parameter, but `{}` is not false, so by doing so `useParams() || props`, if there isn't an `userId` parameter in you your url, you will always get undefined.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have imported `useParams`. If you have imported it already, then try doing this.

```
let { userId } = useParams();
if(!userId) userId = props.userId;
```

Comment: useParams was declared currently so It seems it cant check in inline

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a class component, you must use `withRouter()` instead.

```
import { withRouter } from "react-router";


class Whatever extends Component {
  render() {
    const { userId } = this.props.match.params;
    return null;
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but it wrapped in a functional component . best regards